# Data Processing Engine Runtimen platform choices grayed out

Tags: tableau-crm, crm-analytics

I am trying to create a new Data Processing Engine Definition.
When I get to the second screen where it says "select the runtime platform" I'm presented with two choices: "CRM Analytics" or "Data Cloud" but both choices are grayed out, as is the "Done" button.

I have the following permission sets:
Rule Engine Designer
Data Pipelines Base User
Rule Engine Runtime

Is there a permission set or object I'm missing?  I was able to do this in a personal developer org but now that I'm trying to do it in our sandbox, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Data Pipelines was not enabled in the org!

Quick Start> Data Pipelines -> Getting Started -> Enable

Super embarrassing but glad there was an easy fix.